# How to configure nginx to list directory content

Tags: nginx

I want to setup NGINX to serve as an image content server.

Below is my configure file.

When I try to access http://localhost/images, I always got 403 Forbidden error. What else I missed?

```
http{
    server{
            listen  80;
            root    /Users/user/Pictures;
            location /images {
                    autoindex on;
            }
    }
}

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

Comment: Do you seted up the right access rights? chown nginx:nginx /users

Comment: I set the permission to be 777 and now I got 404 not found error. When I access http://localhost/index.html, it will show the correct page. But when I access the http://localhost/images I got 404 error.

Comment: Do you have index.html? Did you set nginx user for those path?

Comment: Yes, I have index.html and I am able to see the index.html

Comment: Besides, I am able to access to http://localhost/index.html but can't access http://localhost/images/index.html.

Comment: http://localhost/images/index.html ?